# Use static resource in the behaviors

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `textbox` and added a behavior:

```
<TextBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                 FontSize="22" >
            <Binding Path="IpAddr" ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors="True">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <local:IpAddressRule />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:TextBoxInputMaskBehavior InputMask="{StaticResource InputMaskIp}" PromptChar="0" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBox>
```

Now I have moved the `TextBoxInputMaskBehavior` in the resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <system:String x:Key="InputMaskIp">000.000.000.000</system:String>
        <behaviors:TextBoxInputMaskBehavior x:Key="mask" InputMask="{StaticResource InputMaskIp}" PromptChar="0" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Now my question is, how can I bind the resources to:

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    //Will bind resources here.
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Interaction.Behaviors` is a read only `BehaviorCollection` inheriting from `AttachableCollection<Behavior>` & on which you can not set binding.